# How can I detect sub-second interruptions in mains electricity supply?

Tags: electrical, tools, troubleshooting

**TL;DR: Is there a cheap and simple tool for detection of very brief mains power outages?**

Long story and explanation:

Yesterday and today we experienced three or four interruptions in mains electricity supply - some appliances with switched power supply units (PC screens, LED lights) flickered or failes for a very brief period of time, while appliances with good ol' transformer+rectifier setup (like the clock display on the oven panel) didn't seem to be bothered by them.

I firmly believe that we have had many of these in past two years, as these glitches manifest themselves by various strange effects that I can't find better explanations for (fridge-freezer box somehow stops refrigerating and sounds an alarm few hours later, the wifi access point seems to brown out and functions very erratically until next restart, one PC headless restarts itself).

I've had the utility guy over today, he measured our mains tap (voltage, impedance, inter-phase impedance difference etc.) and he said everything looked good on their part so he can't really do anything. He further said I need to check my own wiring, which I will do, but I suspect there is something amiss at the utility since the whole building of 5 units experinces similar weird occurrences as we do. Lastly, he said I should talk to our neighbors and ask if they have similar problems. If they do, he'll come back and do more checks (we are connected to an underground cable which may be failing somewhere but he has no means of detecting that before a full blown failure and as per his measurements right now everything looks good).

Now it took me some two years to actually witness this phenomena, as it usually happened when I was away or in broad daylight with no lights on, and one could only guess we had this brief outage hours later when the fridge/wifi problems manifested themselves. I'm a bit on the technical side of thing, whereas my neighbors are not. Which means even if I ask them, I doubt they won't be able to give me a definite answer whether they, too, get these glitches.

So I'm thinking if I could get them some simple and power efficient gadget for them to plug in to their own socket somewhere, I could just ask them whether the thing has gone dark/silent/pop/kaboom lately, and we all would get a nice answer to a complicated question.

All I could think of was a relay feedback loop which must be manually "activated" and the loop will open on power failure in the relay. But I would prefer a off-the-shelf solution one can buy chaply in a shop, as I don't really want to give my nice neighbors a strange gadget I engineered to put into their wall sockets (and I'm not certified to manufacture such things either).

I specifically don't ask about checking my own electrical installation, as I'll have a professional do it. Also our wiring is three years old and had to be checked officially before we were actually allowed to move in and use it.

Our location is the Czech Republic, Europe. We have three phase 240 V burried cable mains with 8 separate meters for various units, staircase etc.

Comment: I wonder if it’s a lost neutral. On your main circuit breaker,how many throws tied together are there? 1 or 3?

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Three. There is the hree phase main breaker in the meter cabinet and then in each unit there is again a three phase main switch.

Comment: A UPS for your computer will A) protect the computer against (no guarantee of complete protection from) possible damage from power drops, and B) it should provide a record of every time it switches to battery backup. This will help you confirm that the problem is mains power related.

Comment: @FreeMan I _do_ know it is, I'm looking for a simple solution to give to my neigbors who are not technically minded and won't like something like a ups with a computer connected to it for the sole purpose of recording outages. I do have a UPS, but I'd rather find the cause of problems than install and maintain a 7kw UPS for the whole unit...

Comment: Were these brief interruptions causing any problem with your a/c compressor? A brief interruption causes my scroll compressor (29 years in service) to run backwards under power and if I don't intervene, it runs backwards until it overheats and trips the thermal relay. Then it is an hour or two till the compressor cools unless I open the access panel and run water on the compressor. If I  am home and I detect one of these (lights blink off, computer backup power supply clicks), then I manually switch the a/c off at the thermostat, wait 5 min, then it starts and runs with no problem.

Comment: @JimStewart you should post that problem as a question. It might be the start-up capacitor and/or the start-up winding. If it's broken, you get stuttery start-up and possibly in reverse.

Comment: @Pavel -- does your UPS have an event-log function? (many more sophisticated units do)

Comment: @JimStewart I'm lucky to live in the part of the world where I don't (yet) need one, but it may very well be the problem my fridge has! I'll try and check what's going on next time.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel I haven't checked yet, a log with timestamps would be a great help! It's an old entry-level APC with a serial port, so even if it doesn't, I guess I'll be able to get some sort of log over serial to some sort of raspberry/VM with USB serial. the important thing is to plug the logging computer into the UPS :-)

Comment: Well if your apartment gets 3 phases, then it's worth paying very close attention to the voltage on each phase as large loads are turned on and off.  They should be equal (220? 230?) If they wander around as loads change, then look to see if some go *above* normal. That's a lost neutral. In particular, the heavily loaded phase will be pulled *down*, pushing the other phases *up*.  Large motor starts will make this quite acute.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Thank you for the tip, I'll definitely do that! I measured one socket and it says 242V, same as the utility guy measured in their box. I'll be opening the distribution panel in my unit today or tomorrow, so I'll have convenient access to all three phases and will do the measurements there.

Comment: In a perfect world get something like a - do they have [Kill-A-Watt's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kill_A_Watt) in the EU? But a thing that plugs into an outlet and lives there, often giving measurements of a thing plugged into it.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica I have one, but it doesn't have voltage readout, and none on the market have. They only show watts (not even VAs) and in my experience they lag noticeably. But yes, in essence I'm asking about exactly such a thing in my question. Power regulations, sockets and wiring standards are wildly different through the EU, so it may well be something is available in the UK or Spain and not where I live and I just don't know about its existence...

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica -- there are similar gadgets in the EU (watch BigClive's vids)

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would solder your self-latching relay solution. It's simple. If you don't like working with 240V, maybe an AC relay after a transformer or even a DC relay after a USB charger could work. Of course, check to make sure it triggers on brief interruptions.

You can even connect a clock to the switched side (e.g. a timer - but one with a mechanical motor) and determine when the outage happened based on when the clock stopped.

Have you looked at "power logger" "voltage logger" or "energy logger"? You'd have to check the specs if glitches are recorded. A "data logger" and the "voltage logger" are likely the most versatile to log brief/glitch events.

Alternatively, you can

- record the DC voltage after a usb charger and a tone generator using a voice recorder app, and use a simple computer script or audio editor to find the time and duration. Or record the AC hum/cycle, double it to 100Hz using a rectifier bridge, in case 50Hz is filtered out before recording.
- use a video triggered webcam directed at a light to get the time info. The ensuing "dark flash" would have to trigger a recording, and it can even notify you by WiFi
- hook up a relay to an alarm circuit, a cheap one with WiFi/internet notification and logging.

If any of these get close to what you would like to try, we can discuss the details if needed, to help you further along.

Comment: Look for data loggers - Campbell is a name that comes to mind

Comment: @SolarMike, yes good point, I should mention that too. That would be my favourite engineering solution. Will edit answer.

Comment: solid answer though +1...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I'll look into the data loggers. The rest of what you propose isn't applicable as I can't attend to my "boxes" once installed. I need a simple plug-in gadget which with a green/red light or an on/off light, so that my neighbors can plug it themselves and tell me "hey your thing has gone dark yesterday" when it does. They are possibly very interesting, though, for others who may come across looking to solve their own problem!

Comment: Good luck @Pavel . It helps that you are clear about how you plan to use it and what you do and don't expect from it.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.  I've used in my engineering life, many years ago, a printIing circular 7-day clock.  This was a wind up clock with a printing needle on
circular graph paper.  When connected to the power line, it scribes a circular straight line.  If power is momentarily or for longer term droppes, the ink trace will show it.

I haven't been able to find one of these 7 day power monitoring clocks, but I know that they did exist at one time.

Comment: You can use a wall wall wart that outputs AC, to power your relay circuit, then you are not working with the mains.